# detailed plan of schedule vs. detailed planning of schedule

Tags: articles

> Presenters at the Alexander International Convention were reminded
>   that detailed ***plan/ planning*** of the schedule would enable the program
>   to end on time.

Are the both '***plan***' and '***planning***' an option here? Or do we need an article '***a***' in front of 'detailed' when using '***plan***'?

Comment: "Plan" refers to the document.  "Planning" refers to the process of creating the document.  Both can be "detailed", so both are ok in this context. However the way you would phrase the sentence is different for each.  Also, yes, it should be "a plan" but not "a planning".

Comment: You wouldn't normally include an article with the gerund ***planning***, but you need one with *They were reminded that **a** detailed plan [would be necessary]* (in some circumstances you could use ***the***, but usually not).

Comment: Actually it's difficult to come up with a good example in this case since "plan" is not the right word for this context.  Why would presenters **plan** the schedule?  Usually the **Planning Committee** would plan the schedule and then give it to the presenters to follow.  Instead it sounds like you want to say that the presenters should *follow* the schedule so the program can end on time, or "stick to the time constraints" or various others.

Comment: If the convention did something, what did they say??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your quote talks about making a schedule to help the program finish in a timely manner.

The available choices are:

1. the existence of a detailed plan of the schedule - this might refer to a particular layout of the schedule; or
2. detailed planning of the schedule - this refers to the process of considering the schedule at a fine granularity.

Of the two, *planning* makes more sense in context. The existence, or even the possession, of a detailed version of the schedule is less helpful for keeping the program on time than thinking about the schedule carefully.

> **planning** *noun*
>   1 The process of making plans for something.
>   ‘mass production methods call for detailed planning’
>   [- ODO](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/planning)